# Hooking together ports in dpdk_testpmd

Tags: networking, dpdk

I currently have this command line for setting up a simple test environment for pumping a PCAP file to a TAP socket:

```
sudo dpdk-testpmd -l 0-3 -n 4 \
     --vdev 'net_pcap0,rx_pcap=/path/to/input.pcap' \
     --vdev 'net_tap0,mac=fixed' \
     -- -i --no-flush-rx
```

This works (eg WireShark detects `tap0` and captures the data being pumped), but how can I query the internal paths to make sure the correct routes are there? If I use more `vdev` parameters, I need to make sure everything is behaving itself.

On [this page](https://doc.dpdk.org/guides/howto/pvp_reference_benchmark.html#testpmd-launch) it suggests that:

```
set portlist <list>
```

Can be used to hook things together, but I cannot see how to query that setting. Using:

```
show port info all
```

Doesn't seem to provide that information.

Answer (score 1):

When you run the `start` command line you will get the below output. With this, you can get an idea whose rx is connected with whose tx.

```
Logical Core 1 (socket 1) forwards packets on 2 streams:
  RX P=0/Q=0 (socket 0) -> TX P=1/Q=0 (socket 0) peer=02:00:00:00:00:01
  RX P=1/Q=0 (socket 0) -> TX P=0/Q=0 (socket 0) peer=02:00:00:00:00:00
```

Moreover, check out [--port-topology=mode](http://doc.dpdk.org/guides/testpmd_app_ug/run_app.html)